# Mouse DirectInput for OSX

Tags: macos, mouse

Does anybody know of some code I can look at that tracks mouse input on a Mac like DirectInput does in Windows? I'm trying to implement "freeview" on a Mac. I've read that the HID Manager is the way to go, but I'm not sure where to start on it ...

Comment: I don't know what DirectInput is... what do you need beyond mouse events normally received by Mac apps?  Do you need to see mouse events directed to other apps than your own?  Do you need to actually change the mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.5+, HID Manager is the way to go. Use [ManyMouse](https://icculus.org/manymouse/) to take away some of the pain (unfortunately, ManyMouse does not support device hotplugging, but that is trivial to implement.)